# Localhost express routing does not work

Tags: node.js

I have a node project on localhost which works for months.
Today there was an update on my Mac.
Now when I am trying to access the node project via browser **on localhost** I just get a blank screen.
But **on my VPS** the same project works as expected.

On terminal, there is log says that node is up and running but when I am trying to access some api I just got an error.

This is the main app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs("mongodb://user:pass@ip:port/dbname", []);
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var cors = require('cors');
var request = require('request');
var fcm = require('./routes/fcm');
var Excel = require('exceljs');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');

var limiter = new rateLimit({
  windowMs: 10*60*1000, // 10 minutes
  max: 100, // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs (11 is on load and more 100 later on)
  delayMs: 0, // disable delaying - full speed until the max limit is reached
  message: "נחסמת ל-10 דקות בעקבות שימוש לא סביר בשרת - נסה במועד מאוחר יותר"
});

//  apply to all requests
app.use(limiter);

app.use(cors());

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src'));

// just for check if a simple call working:
app.get("/checkthis", function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("Yes");
});

require('./routes/sockets')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request, fcm);
require('./routes/userServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request, fcm, rateLimit);
require('./routes/ridesServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request);
require('./routes/offersServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request, rateLimit);
require('./routes/notificationsServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request);
require('./routes/scopeServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request, fcm);
require('./routes/excelServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request, fcm, Excel, fs, path);

server.listen("8080", function() {
  console.log("Connected to db and listening on port 8080");
});
```

As I said the `console.log("Connected to db and listening on port 8080");`
is seen in the Terminal log.

When I am trying to access an undefined URL like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/asdasd
```

I suppose to receive an automatic message saying: `Cannot /GET asdasd`
But I just got the next error:

```
This 127.0.0.1 page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: http://127.0.0.1:8080/checkthis
HTTP ERROR 404
```

Maybe should I re-install node.js due to the update that Apple did?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing forward slash for route, everything else is working, check this:

```
app.get("/checkthis", function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("Yes");
});
```

Comment: This not the problem. I have added this "checkthis" just for a manual check if everything works, I have added the "/" again, still not work in localhost but works in VPS.

Comment: I checked your code, commented `./routes/sockets` part and everything is working. I was able to get response `yes` for `http://localhost:8080/checkthis`.

Comment: What do you mean you have checked my code and that you were enable to get the response?

Comment: I ran your code locally. excluding some of the lines which i am not able to access